# Add a number of cells that only have a 1 in them

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Is there any way for me to add a bunch of cells that only have a 1 in them? If they have a 0 in them, then this should not be added to the total. This should also work if the list is filtered too.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* that you mean that you want to ***count*** the number of cells with 1 in them?

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,">0")
```

Will give you a count of the number of cells in column A containing a number greater than zero, change the test to `=1` to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just add them all since 0 will not affect the value?

Comment: well that is pointless, cos if I do =SUM(F2:F49) it still adds up all of the cells with 0 in them too, I don't want them added!!!

Comment: @harry If you add 0 to a sum, it won't add anything. Can you clarify your question by maybe including a more specific example?

Comment: @pnuts No idea. The OP never came back to clarify, so I've closed that question now.